# Does OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN mean atomic or nonatomic?

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-runtime

Does `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN`, the fourth argument of `objc_setAssociatedObject`, mean atomic or nonatomic?

This enum is defined as

```
enum {
    OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN = 0,
    OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC = 1,
    OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC = 3,
    OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN = 01401,
    OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY = 01403
};
```

What is for `@property(assign, atomic) id idAssignAtomic;`?

What is for `@property(assign, nonatomic) id idAssignNonatomic;`?

Comment: One would assume non-atomic, by the numbering scheme.

Comment: As for atomic versus nonatomic assignment, CLANG generates the same code for both with object properties, it's only reading where the former guarantees you a whole value and the latter leaves you on your own.

Comment: @CodaFi So you mean that `OBJC_ASSOCIATION_ASSIGN` is for both `@property(assign, atomic)` and `@property(assign, nonatomic)`?
I need to know about it to make https://github.com/kissrobber/DProperty

Comment: Associated objects make no guarantees of atomicity (at least, not publicly).  Assume nonatomic.

Comment: Considering this question again, for values of type `ASSIGN`, aren't concerns about atomicity actually irrelevant (at least from a public perspective)?

If you compare atomic/nonatomic to their equivalents when used on an objective-c property, the 'atomicity' of a property that is also 'assign' and has the same size as a pointer on all of the platforms that iOS/OSX support is actually *irrelevant*, as stores of word size are always going to be atomic at the processor level.

The important distinction here for atomicity comes with retain/release's behavior, NOT the storage of the value.

Comment: The fact that the implementation acquires locks to ensure that internal state remains consistent inside the hash-table actually isn't relevant to the question, especially when you consider it as a comparison to normal objective-c properties.

Answer (score 1):

Currently (as of iOS 8 and OS X 10.10), internally all associations are made atomically. This can be seen if we look at the source of `objc-references.mm`:

```
// class AssociationsManager manages a lock / hash table singleton pair.
// Allocating an instance acquires the lock, and calling its assocations() method
// lazily allocates it.

class AssociationsManager {
    static spinlock_t _lock;
    static AssociationsHashMap *_map;               // associative references:  object pointer -> PtrPtrHashMap.
public:
    AssociationsManager()   { spinlock_lock(&_lock); }
    ~AssociationsManager()  { spinlock_unlock(&_lock); }

    AssociationsHashMap &associations() {
        if (_map == NULL)
            _map = new AssociationsHashMap();
        return *_map;
    }
};
```

Specifically, note that `_lock` and `_map` are both static, and defined as such:

```
spinlock_t AssociationsManager::_lock = SPINLOCK_INITIALIZER;
AssociationsHashMap *AssociationsManager::_map = NULL;
```

And then, when both getting an association and releasing it, we see the following:

```
AssociationsManager manager;
AssociationsHashMap &associations(manager.associations());
```

Which clearly indicates that every association is atomic, and independent of all other associations being stored or retrieved in the process.

Remember, though, that as with anything in the runtime, this is all subject to change with a future release, and you should NOT rely on this behavior for anything other than academic purposes.

Comment: Hi, so should one still assume it to be non-atomic from your comment above or atomic as per your answer? I would have also assumed it to be non-atomic due to performance reasons. Am just guessing. Thanks.

Comment: @Unheilig always go by public documentation where you can. So in this case, assume it's non-atomic, even if as an implementation detail it is atomic.

Comment: Though I agree with you that we should always go by the public documentation; however, how could they make it work when, let's say, it is atomic in the implementation detail whilst it is claimed non-atomic in the documentation? Am just curious about these nitty-gritty details on how things tick behind the scenes, although I know "_it just works_" without me needing to know how it does. Thanks.